# Display two tables in one page

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to insert two tables in one page of RShiny Web Application. 
I wrote:

```
shinyApp(
  shinyUI(tableOutput('table1'),
          tableOutput('table2')),
  shinyServer(function(input, output){
    output$table1 <- renderTable(mtcars)
    output$table2 <- renderTable(iris)
  })
)
```

But it is giving me an error message as below:

> Error in shinyUI(tableOutput("table1"), tableOutput("table2")) :
>   unused argument (tableOutput("table2"))

Don't understand because when I print out table1 or table2 only, it worked fine. It is just when I try to print two tables at the same time, I have the "unused argument" error.

Why does this error occur? 
How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: This is much easier to do with shinydashboard package. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput('table1'),
  tableOutput('table2')
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {
  output$table1 <- renderTable(mtcars)
  output$table2 <- renderTable(iris)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```